# Why bounded continuous functions in probability on metric spaces?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

> **Theorem 1.1.8** Every probability measure $P$ on $(S, \mathcal{S})$ is regular; that is, for every $\mathcal{S}$-set $A$ and every $\epsilon$ there exist a closed set $F$ and an open set $G$ such that $F \subset A \subset G$ and $P(G-F)<\epsilon$.

> Theorem $1.1$ implies that $P$ is completely determined by the values of $P F$ for closed sets $F$. The next theorem shows that $P$ is also determined by the values of $P f$ for bounded, continuous $f$. The proof depends on approximating the indicator $I_F$ by such an $f$, and the function $f(x)=(1-\rho(x, F) / \epsilon)^{+}$works. It is bounded, and it is continuous, even uniformly continuous, because $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \rho(x, y) / \epsilon$. And $x \in F$ implies $f(x)=1$, while $x \notin F^\epsilon$ implies $\rho(x, F) \geq \epsilon$ and hence $f(x)=0$. Therefore,
> $$
> (1.1) \quad I_F(x) \leq f(x)=(1-\rho(x, F) / \epsilon)^{+} \leq I_{F^\epsilon}(x)
> $$
> **Theorem 1.2.*8 Probability measures $P$ and $Q$ on $\mathcal{S}$ coincide if $P f=Q f$ for all bounded, uniformly continuous real functions $f$.

I feel I don't have good intuition why, of all classes of functions, integrating bounded, continuous functions are natural to do here. Of course, we are on a metric space so we can approximate our events by open and closed sets, via the regularity, but what is motivating us to look at $Pf=\int_{S}f dP$? Isn't the set of all continuous functions really large? This feels unwieldy to me. **Essentially, I'm looking at the expectations of all contiuous random variables on my probability space over a metric space?** What good will this do for me?

Comment: [1](https://almostsuremath.com/2019/11/10/algebraic-probability/) "By the monotone class theorem, we can uniquely represent probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ by the expectations on any subset $\mathcal K\subseteq L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ which is closed under taking products and generates the sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$."